# Running BASH cgi script

Tags: apache, bash

I am not root. I have written and placed a script in the cgi-bin of my apache server. The code is too long for here, but in a nutshell, the script is called from a browser and a filename argument is also passed as a URL parameter. The script takes the filename, locates the file and reads it. The file contains a simple list of files/locations to be copied. The script iterates through each line of the file and copies the file on that line from the current server to a remote server using ssh and standard rsync commands. It's all pretty standard stuff.

The script runs perfectly from command line, all files are copied correctly. When launched from the browser, the script appears to function perfectly. It throws no errors and debug logs tell me everything was copied fine, only the actual files themselves are not actually copied.

I'm assuming it has something to do with the script being run by apache (or wwwroot) in the cgi-bin, which is not the script owner, as I am.  As I am not root, I cannot change ownership or use sudo. Any ideas on getting this to work?

Comment: It sounds like what you are doing is pretty dangerous from a security perspective... is BASH really the right tool to do this with? Also, why does this script need to SSH or run rsync to copy the file? That sounds like a very expensive operation to do in the standard serving path (that should probably be a precomputation).

Comment: Please tell me that you've secured the hell out of this thing, somehow?

Comment: Your need whatever user the script is running as to have permission to read and write the files from and to the locations that are needed.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. This is on a secure closed intranet, only 2 people have access to the server. Currently it's just an exercise to see if it can be done so please disregard the bells going off in your heads. ssh is not used for the rsync but to create a target directory on the remote server if one doesn't exist, sorry I should have made that clearer.

Comment: As the script is non-interactive when run from browser, you must have configured  passwordless login right? For which user did you create the passwordless login? If its for the shell user and not the apache user, non-interatcive scp/rsync will fail for the second case. I would recommend  logging-in as apache or www-data and enabling passwordless login. You might have to edit /etc/passwd to login as the webserver user